# Forward SSH port - Connect from other place

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, nat

I have a home server behind a NAT. At work I'm also behind a NAT. So to connect from work to my home server I would have to port forward the SSH port in my router at home to the WAN interface.

Would it also be possible to have a permanent ssh tunnel from my home server to a webserver I own. Then when I connect from work I connect to the webserver and let it tunnel to the SSH server on my home server.

And if possible, what would be the security implications?

### Servers

- Home server (behind NAT)
- Webserver
- Client (behind NAT)

### Connections

- Home server --> permanent SSH tunnel --> webserver
- Client --> connects to --> webserver --> gets forwarded to --> Home server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your home server connect using `ssh -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22 user@domain.tld -N`

This will open a ssh session to your webserver.

The `-R 2222:127.0.0.1:22` maps port `2222` on the remote server to be redirected to the IP address:port specified in your case `127.0.0.1:22`

Use `-N` if you don't want an interactive session.

On the client connect to your webserver using `ssh -p 2222 user@webserver.tld` 
you must specify the port since it's not the default.

You also have open the port in your firewall configuration.